# Class declaration inside function parameter list

Tags: c++, parameters, language-lawyer

As I understand, in C++, a class declared inside function parameter list automatically goes to the enclosing scope:

```
void f(struct A *p) {}

void g() { A *p; f(p); }
```

is equivalent to:

```
struct A;

void f(A *p) {}

void g() { A *p; f(p); }
```

What section in C++ standard specifies this behavior? What about C?

Well, I guess C does not follow C++ in this case. Visual studio does not compile this code is C mode:

```
void g(struct A { int a; } a);

struct A a;     // 'a' uses undefined struct 'A'
```

Comment: Your last example doesn't compile in C++ either.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to note that C++ does not allow class definition inside function parameter list. I meant that C does not follow C++ in that case where class declaration inside parameter list 'leaks' into function declaration scope.

Answer (score 4):

This is an *elaborated-type-specifier*. The relevant quote in C++14 is:

> `[basic.lookup.elab]/2:` [...] If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by
>   the *class-key* and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or if the *elaborated-type-specifier*
>   appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> ```
> class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;
> ```
>
> the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the class-name as described in 3.3.2.

This declares the class name like so:

> `[basic.scope.pdecl]/7:` The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> — [...]
>
> — for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
> ```
> class-key identifier
> ```
>
> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* **or parameter-declaration-clause of a function defined in namespace scope**, the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the
>   smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.

So because `struct A` is an *elaborated-type-specifier* and `A` has not been previously declared, `A` is declared in the namespace that contains the declaration (in this case, the global namespace).